# Style sheet must be inline

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, styles, inline

I created a fancy button and two text styles . These style works fine inline in the head of the html but when I link to an external css file it fails. Only the text styles look good or the button style but together they never work. It seems that something prevents the other style to work somehow...

Thanks in advance

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>thanks</title>

    <style>

    .button4 {
    background-color: #ff6600;
    border: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 16px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    font-size: 22px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    transition-duration: 0.9s;
    cursor: pointer;

    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:8px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:8px;
    border-top-left-radius:8px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:8px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:8px;
    border-top-right-radius:8px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:8px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:8px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:8px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:8px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:8px;  

}



.button4:hover {
  background-color: #ff9900;
  color: white;
}

.button4:focus {
    outline: none;

}

.title {
    text-align: center;
    font: 600 65px/120% Helvetica, Arial;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #666666;
    padding-top: 200px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0px;
}

.text {
    text-align: center;
    font: 600 20px/120% Helvetica, Arial;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #666666;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0px;

}   

</style>    
</head>


<body>

    <p class="title">title</p>
    <div class="text">text</div>

<button class="button4" id="buttonId" >Button</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using "!important". Because it will load the default styles. I think that's why when using inline it works. Use as follows

```
background-color: #ff6600 !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if the external CSS is affecting your code, use the developer tool of your web browser. From the developer tool you will be able to see how the different CSS lines are affecting the elements of your page and correct your code.